# How do I allow only my domain and some external domain to post to Google Group via email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-groups, access-control

Currently I got this to work so far:

I got Google Apps for Work for my company "Contoso" and I have set up a distribution list via Google Groups so that anyone in the company can send an email to `techsupport@contoso.tld` and only members of the support group will receive it. All external users will get a bounce if they try to send an email to this list.

I am stuck on the next bit, we got close partnership with people with `@partner1.tld` and `@partner2.tld`, and wish to open up our techsupport list to them too, but not anyone else on the internet... how do I do that?

Currently there is only one email address for `@partner1.tld`, and not many for `@partner2.tld`, so if we were to add extra addresses that are allowed to post the the list that might work for a while too.

EDIT: basically we just need techsupport list to reject all emails unless they are from `@contoso.tld`, `@partner1.tld` and `@partner2.tld`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this currently, but there is one thing you can do

> 1. Create a group with the same members and add the additional external emails to the group as well
> 2. Ask them to post on the group when required
> 3. Set permissions as restricted

Downside is that other people from their team will also get the email.